# mimic :hover css using a css class

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a series of divs that I use to create a "star rating" input.
Normally the stars are gray, when the mouse goes over one of the stars the stars fills with a color, and that it's working.

Now I want a class that "mimic" the :hover behaviour and I called it `active` so when I put that class the stars fills with the color, but that is not working.

Here the code:

HTML

```
<span class="rating">
 <span class="star active"></span>
 <span class="star"></span>
 <span class="star"></span>
 <span class="star"></span>
 <span class="star"></span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.rating span.star:before {
    content: "\f005";
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #bbb;
}

.rating span.star:hover:before, .rating span.star.active, .rating span.star:hover ~ span.star:before {
    color: #ffbe0d;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuTfX/

I am using FontAwesome to display the stars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `:before` to the `.active` rule.
Change

```
.rating span.star:hover:before, .rating span.star.active, .rating span.star:hover ~ span.star:before {
    color: #ffbe0d;
}
```

To

```
.rating span.star:hover:before, .rating span.star.active:before, .rating span.star:hover ~ span.star:before {
    color: #ffbe0d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try (I moved the color on `:before` to just the `span`):

```
.rating span.star {
    color: #bbb;
}
.rating span.star:before {
    content: "\f005";
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.rating span.star:hover:before, .rating span.star.active, .rating span.star:hover ~ span.star:before {
    color: #ffbe0d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scrap Approach and Implement Pyramidal Absolute Positioning

JSFIDDLE---> http://jsfiddle.net/5n5Xt/

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Rating 1 of 5</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Rating 2 of 5</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Rating 3 of 5</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Rating 4 of 5</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Rating 5 of 5</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { background: url(gray_stars.png) no-repeat; width: 120px; height: 20px; position: relative;}
li a { display: block; position: absolute; top 0; height: 20px; left: 0;
li:first-child a { width: 20px; z-index: 5;}
li + li a { width: 40px; z-index: 4;}
li + li + li a { width: 60px; z-index: 3;}
li + li + li + li a { width: 80px; z-index: 2;}
li + li + li + li + li a { width: 100px; z-index: 1;}
li + a:hover {background: url(yellow_stars.png) no-repeat;}
ul li span { display: none;}
```

## How it Works

Basically your stars created a overlapping rectangular shapes. The 1st star comprises of a 20x20 box with the highest z-index -> making it the first star and on top of all the stars. The 2nd star is a rectangle that comprises of the first star + the second star . Its z-index makes it BELOW the first star but just like the first star, it will be overlapped by the consecutive stars. -> repeat this for all 5 stars so that each star has a 20x20 region that is "hoverable" at any given time. Since each star anchor is actually the "full length" from the left side if you hover star 4 -> all 80px is activated and you see 4 golden stars. But then when you go to star 3, only star 3 activated -> 3 stars show up.

Hope that explains it. I threw together a quick jsfiddle that I hope will help you. I used plain colors but you see the 1-5 "yellow" boxes color up when hovered.